# MVC.NET Access to a Post Method from an external Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a Web Application in MVC3.NET working ok in a Local Machine in an Intranet.
Now I need to have another project in Web Hosting that has to access to some method from the previous app.

But when I do the Post with jQuery, the other app returned an HTTP error 500.

The idea is that I need to log in and make some things in the computer in the intranet from the other application in a  web hosting.

Here you have the jQuery method in the Web Hosting:

```
function enviar(frase,mostrar) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://xxxx:8022/ControllerA/Method",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: $.toJSON(frase),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.exito) {
            if(mostrar)
                alert('Su mensaje ha sido enviado.');
        }
        else {
            alert(data.mensaje);
            if (data.error == 2) {
                window.location = "/Home/LogOff";
            }

        }
    }
});}
```

And here the code from the Local Machine:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createPhrases(FrasesModel model)
    {
        int IdNegocio = 1;
        try 
        {           
                 //SomeLogic
                return Json(new { success= true });
            }
            else {
                return Json(new { success= false, error=2 });   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json(new { success= false, error = 1 }); 
        }

    }
```

Do I need some specific configuration in the WebConfig or Global.aspx?